# arclength of vector r

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

$$r(t) = \langle 2t, t^2, \ln t \rangle.$$

I know that to find arclength you do
$$L = \int_a^b \|r'(t)\| ~dt.$$

I found $r'(t)$ to be $r'(t) = \left\langle 2, 2t, \dfrac{1}{t} \right\rangle$.

To find $\|r'(t)\|$ I did

$$\sqrt{(2)^2 + (2t)^2 + \dfrac{1}{t^2}}$$

but how do I integrate that?

Comment: Isn't the term that you want to integrate just $|2t+t^{-1}|$?  And the fact that $\ln t$ is defined means that $t$ must be positive; so you can lose the $| |$ signs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: oh! my bad. I fixed it now. There was a typo in the question: there were 3 components.

Comment: I mean, isn't $\sqrt{4+4t^2+t^{-2}}$ exactly the same thing as $|2t+t^{-1}|$.  Try squaring the latter; you'll see.

Comment: $r'(t)$ should be $\left\langle 2, 2t, \dfrac{1}{t} \right\rangle$

Comment: yeah. Typo again sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have shown, 
$$\|r'(t)\|=\sqrt{4t^2+4+\frac{1}{t^2}}
=\sqrt{\left(2t+\frac{1}{t}\right)^2}=2t+\frac{1}{t}.$$
Therefore, the arclength is given by
$$L=\int_a^b \|r'(t)\| ~dt=\int_a^b\left(2t+\frac{1}{t}\right)dt
=(t^2+\log t)\Big|_a^b=b^2-a^2+\log b-\log a.$$

Comment: You should mention that you can drop the absolute value because $t$ has to be positive.

Comment: @JavierBadia: Oh yes, I should mention that. Thanks for pointing it out.